# changes dependencies graph

Tags: gerrit

Is there any external tool or some way to visualise dependency graph between Gerrit's changes ?

In our workflow we often want to find the newest change/patchset starting from some change. As we not always start work from master branch our dependencies are really complex and browsing through dependencies in Gerrit's UI is really not comfortable.

It would be nice to have generated image with dependencies, where nodes will present changes and patch set's number.

Answer (score 0):

Please watch this https://bugs.chromium.org/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=5012 which is the current ticket about this missing feature.

I am trying to find a way to get it working outside gerrit.

Answer (score -1):

There are no other visualization options currently.  You might file a feature request at http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/issues/list.  Keep in mind that contributions to the project are always welcome :)